# Taking Median of two datetime values or columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, timedelta

For the below data I want to take the middle value or the middle time of the first two timestamps in each row and then subract that third timestamp

[image: I want to take the middle value of the first two timestamps and subract that by the third time stamp]

What would be the best way to take the median value or middle datime of two timestamps?

the output expected is in minutes the difference of two timestamps.

It is the median or mean of the first two minus the third timestamp.

it is the middle value or timestamp of `2018-12-21 23:31:24.615` and `2018-12-21 23:31:26.659`.

Once I have that value I want to subtract the third timestamp of `2018-12-21 23:31:27.975`. The output would represent a value of minutes.

Comment: What is the output you expect, also can you please give a [minimal,reproducible ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)example

Comment: Thanks I added some more comment to clarify. Output needed is the value in minutes for the difference of two timestamps - such as A - B.

problem is I want A to be the middle value or the middle time between the first two datetime

Comment: Chris, have you found your solution, if yes and via the below posted answer, I would request you to accept one that helped you finding one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the df looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'time1':['2018-12-21 23:31:24.615','2018-12-22 01:33:26.015'],'time2':['2018-12-21 23:31:26.659','2018-12-22 01:33:32.865'],'time3':['2018-12-21 23:31:27.975','2018-12-22 01:59:05.136']})

    time1                   time2                   time3
0   2018-12-21 23:31:24.615 2018-12-21 23:31:26.659 2018-12-21 23:31:27.975
1   2018-12-22 01:33:26.015 2018-12-22 01:33:32.865 2018-12-22 01:59:05.136
```

Convert 'to_datetime'

```
df[['time1','time2','time3']] = df[['time1','time2','time3']].apply(pd.to_datetime,errors='coerce')
```

creating a column having the average of the first 2 columns:

```
my_list= []
for i in df.index:
    my_list.append(pd.to_datetime((df['time1'][i].value + df['time2'][i].value)/2.0))
df['avg'] = my_list
```

or simply :

```
df['avg'] = [(pd.to_datetime((df['time1'][i].value + df['time2'][i].value)/2.0)) for i in df.index]
```

finding difference of column3 and avg:

```
(df.time3-df.avg).astype('timedelta64[m]')
```

output:

```
0     0.0
1    25.0
dtype: float64
```

P.S : you have to replace columns `time1`,`time2` and `time3` with the column names in your dataframe.