# adding,subtracting datetime.time columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have following dataframe

```
flight_departure   arrival_at_desination   boarding  total_flight_time   total_flight_time/2    time_to_collect_bags
0:00                     4:00               23:30           4:00                  2:00                     4:30
9:00                     14:30              8:30            5:30                  2:45                      15:00

flight_departure- 0:00 signifies 12:00 AM
arrival_at_desination- 4:00 signifies 4 AM
boarding = flight_departure-30 minutes(23:30)
total_flight_time=arrival_at_desination-flight_departure(4 hours)

total_flight_time/2-calculates hald time(2 hours in this case)
time_to_collect_bags=arrival_at_desination+30 minutes(4:30AM)
```

When I try to do the following

```
df['arrival_at_desination']-df['flight_departure']
```

It gives me following error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
```

how should I subtract two datetime.time columns?

Comment: Uhmm... can the .sub() method work on this ? Did you try ?

Comment: It gives me exactly the same error when i try df['arrival_at_desination']-df['flight_departure']

Comment: `(df['arrival_at_desination']-df['flight_departure']).astype('timedelta64[m]')` how does this work?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53940340/taking-median-of-two-datetime-values-or-columns/53941396#53941396) answer , had solved similar problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to convert to datatime format to convert try this

```
arrival = pd.to_datetime(df['arrival_at_desination'])
dept = pd.to_datetime(df['flight_departure'])
diff = arrival - dept
```

This is what I get, hope this help,

```
0   -1 days +20:00:00
1   -1 days +18:30:00
```

Else add date to the data, concatenate with time and perform the above

Comment: Doesn't work on my install python3. TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'. It needs a combine step.

Answer (score 3):

In general, it's not possible to subtract two times without date information (what if the arrival is at 1am and the departure is 11pm?). If you're assuming they're on the same date, and the time of arrival is always greater than the time of departure, you could do the following. It's not pretty and hopefully someone comes along with a better answer.

```
(pd.to_datetime(df.arrival_at_desination.astype(str), format='%H:%M:%S') -
    pd.to_datetime(df.flight_departure.astype(str), format='%H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: Thanks I don't know how but your first line was enough for the solution actually the only way possible is to have complete date and time data together as one value in both columns and then you can subtract them and get your desired result.

Answer (score 1):

I found that to make this work (python3.68), you need to combine the time with a date -- real or fake.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['to','fr','ans'])

date = "1-1-01 "
tmp = pd.Series(['13:03:12','11:57:18','10:07:47'])
tm =pd.to_datetime(date+tmp, format='%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S')

tmp = pd.Series(['13:02:12','10:57:18','10:07:22'])
tm2 =pd.to_datetime(date+tmp, format='%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S')

df.to = tm2
df.fr = tm

(df.fr-df.to)
#if you want this as seconds -- which for my applications has been more useful.
(df.fr-df.to).astype('timedelta64[s]')
```